# How do I get my merge sort to use a list I have created somewhere else?

Tags: c#

I have made a merge sort in a class called "MergeSorter" in this I have a public method called DoMergeSort. I also have a Class called "WriteToList" and this is where the list is created and will write to and this code is:  `public static List<int> ListOrderID = new List<int>();`
For me to call my Merge sort I need in one of my windows forms in a class to be able to call ListOrderID.MergeSorter However, it says "The name ListOrderID does not exist in the current context".

I don't really have any idea how I should fix this.

This is the code which is where it is trying to call the list.
My merge sort code is also listed below

```
   private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             MergeSorting();
         }

         public static void MergeSorting()
         {
        


             ListOrderID.DoMergeSort();

             foreach (int number in ListOrderID)
                 Console.WriteLine(number + " ");
         }

 public static class MergeSorter
{
    
    public static void DoMergeSort(this int[] ListOrderID)
    {
        
        var sortedListOrderID = MergeSort(ListOrderID);

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedListOrderID.Length; i++)
        {
            ListOrderID[i] = sortedListOrderID[i];
        }
    }
    private static int[] MergeSort(int[] ListOrderID)
    {
        if (ListOrderID.Length <= 1) return ListOrderID; //base case 

        var left = new List<int>();
        var right = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ListOrderID.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 > 0)
            {
                left.Add(ListOrderID[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                right.Add(ListOrderID[i]);
            }
        }

        left = MergeSort(left.ToArray()).ToList();
        right = MergeSort(left.ToArray()).ToList();

        return Merge(left, right);

    
    }
    private static int[] Merge(List<int> left, List<int> right)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();

        while (NotEmpty(left) && right.Count > 0)
        {
            if (left.First() <= right.First())
            {
                MoveValueFromSourceToResult(left, result);
            }
            else
                MoveValueFromSourceToResult(right, result);
        }

        while (NotEmpty(left))
        {
            MoveValueFromSourceToResult(left, result);
        }
        while (NotEmpty(right))
        {
            MoveValueFromSourceToResult(right, result);
        }

        return result.ToArray();

    }

    private static bool NotEmpty(List<int> list)
    {
        return list.Count > 0;
    }

    private static void MoveValueFromSourceToResult(List<int> list, List<int> result)
    {
        result.Add(list.First());
        list.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

I tried making the List in a public Method I have tried calling the List itself.
I don't really know what else to try.
I am hoping for it to be able to read the List I have saved the stuff to and then just be able to simple order them and output them.

Edit: If possible it would be nice to have it print out into a list box not just a message box.

Comment: Generally, when you create a sort function, you make it generic and you pass two things as parameters: 1) the collection to be sorted (i.e., an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the generic parameter type for your sort function), and 2) a delegate to a method used for comparing two `T` instances (typically a `Func<T, T, int>`). Sorry I can't figure out how your code is expected to work. Please show enough for us to make sense of what you are talking about

Comment: I have added all the code that is within the Merge sort as well if that helps.

Comment: On what line are you getting the order? Instead of making your sort routine an extension method on `int[]` (this `ListOrderID.DoMergeSort()` doesn't really read idiomatically), consider making it generic either with an `IComparable` constraint on `T`, or pass in a delegate to a comparison function (or Lambda) and pass in a collection of `T` to sort.

Answer (score 0):

> The name ListOrderID does not exist in the current context

This means that the compiler does not know what `ListOrderID` refers to. Likely because it is declared as a local variable:

```
public class MyForm{
   public MyForm(){
       var ListOrderID = new []{2, 1, 3}; 
   }
   private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
         ListOrderID.DoMergeSort(); // Error!
   }
}
```

here the *local variable* is declared in the constructor, so it can only be used inside the constructor. If you want to use it in a method you need to change it to a *instance variable* / *field*:

```
public class MyForm{
   int[] ListOrderID = new []{2, 1, 3}; 
   public MyForm(){    }
   private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
         ListOrderID.DoMergeSort(); 
   }
}
```

All this because `ListOrderID` may refer to many different arrays depending on the context. So the compiler need to know what specific array you want to use. You can declare variables as `public static`, giving it *global* scope, but that is frowned upon since it becomes really difficult to understand what and when something accesses the variable.

Comment: I had made it as a public static string and also tried a public void where I had tried to call that which was all in a separate public class. However, it can't even seem to find the Public Void Method when I tried.

Comment: @CluelessGuy what static string? you are sorting integers, no? Did you declare the array `public static`? If so you may need to include the class name when refering to it: `MyForm.MyPublicStaticArray`. Whatever problem you are having with method resolution is a separate problem from resolving the variable.

Comment: I didn't mean string I just meant public static.